# Connection Interrupted error in iOS simulators after updating to xcode 7

Tags: ios, macos, xcode, xcode-simulator

I have updated to Xcode 7 from App Store. And now when ever I run an application or directly start the simulator from Xcode, i got an error **Error Returned in reply: Connection Interrupted**.

[image]

I searched on internet, but did not found any solutions. Kindly advice about this issue.

Comment: Did you restart both the computer and the phone already?

Comment: I did everything. I restarted my laptop and still it did not worked. I am not using phone to test my app right now. I am using simulator.

Comment: OK, i restarted my machine again and it worked now :). Not sure why it was not working before. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I found at the end that I had 2 simulator windows running at the same time. I close both of them and Xcode, and the problem was solved.
I didn't need to restart my machine.

Comment: I had to remove the simulator from dock preferences to run. I didn't need to restart my machine.